# Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have getting user's current location but getting this error  at this line

`let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateSpanMake(myLocation, span)`

I am getting error at **myLocation** in above line

> Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')

I think there may be type casting problem or similar.

What should I do to handle this error I researched a lot of examples but none helped me.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    let location = locations[0]

    let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)
    let myLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateSpanMake(myLocation, span)



    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.myMap.showsUserLocation = true


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `MKCoordinateRegionMake`, not `MKCoordinateSpanMake`.

And there's lots of other fixes you should make:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation = location.coordinate
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)

    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.myMap.showsUserLocation = true
}
```

Comment: This shows the user in San fransico? how to get current state? or on simulator I cant get my current state?

Comment: That's an entirely separate question from the one you originally asked. Did my answer solve your original question? If so, please indicate that by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. As for your latest comment, please do some searching. There is plenty of information on setting the location in the simulator.